# Htaccess redirect folder and remove end of URL

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect some URLs using `.htaccess` but without any success.
The problem is that I have to redirect two different parts of the URL.

Here is an example of what I have to redirect:

```
example.com/huawei-reparatie/huawei-mate-7-reparatie
```

has to be redirected to:

```
example.com/reparatie/huawei/huawei-mate-7
```

So what has to be done:

- Split `huawei-reparatie` into `reparatie/huawei`
- Remove the `-reparatie` at the end of every URL

These are dynamic URLs so it is not only this one. I have to redirect all these URLs for a lot of different brands (like `huawei`) and a lot of different devices (like `huawei-mate-7`)

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did check it but I am not really seeing the solution for me. I think I know to little about rewrites to make any sense of that document.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your requirements:

```
/first-second/text-to-keep-removethis
```

Should redirect to;

```
/second/first/text-to-keep
```

Where

- `first`, `second` and `removethis` contain only lowercase a-z letters.
- `first` and `second` are separated by a single hyphen.
- `removethis` is prefixed by a single hyphen (which is also removed) and always occurs at the end of the URL-path.
- `text-to-keep` is any series of a-z and hyphen characters.

Try the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+?)-[a-z]+$ /$2/$1/$3 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) is a regex that matches against the requested URL-path only, less the slash prefix.

The `$n` in the *substitution* string are backreferences to the corresponding capturing group (parenthesised subpattern) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Any query string present on the initial request will be passed through unaltered. If any query string should be removed then add the `QSD` flag (Query String Discard).

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this is working OK.